# Remove noise from grayscale image PIL

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-imaging-library

I am working on a handwriting recognition code for a school project. We want to collect the data our self, and I’m currently working on a program that scans a document with handwritten letters on it and create a own image for every letter. I cut the image to the exact size of the letter, resize the letter so every letter has the same dimensions and place them on a white background so they have the same dimensions but the original ratio stays the same. I already have it working quite well, the only problem is when I have a little bit of noise in the picture, it doesn’t work. I have the image (see attachment) and a list of all the pixels of the image. What would be a good way to cut the image to the image boundaries and not to the noise.

the code I use to cut the image:

```
def cut_to_edge(image, data, width, height):
    left = width 
    right = 0
    down = 0
    up = height

    for i in range(len(data)):
        for j in range(len(data[i])):
            if data[i][j] < 225:
                if j < left:
                    left = j
                if j > right:
                    right = j
                if i < up:
                    up = i
                if i > down:
                    down = i

    letter = image.crop((left, up, right, down))

    return letter
```

image is the image (obviously),
data is a 2 dimensional list with every pixel ([[row1][row2]etc.]),
width and height are the dimensions of the image

[The image I need to cut,](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b0LqF.png) 
[how it should look,](https://i.stack.imgur.com/60uiE.png) 
[How it looks now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XLeGO.png)

Comment: See https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_photo/py_non_local_means/py_non_local_means.html

Comment: I fixed the problem by using an opencv filter first

Answer (score 0):

If your noise is like little points, you can write a Median filter and that will solve your problem. The main idea of this filter is to loop through the image pixel by pixel and replace each pixel value with the median of the neighboring pixels.

But first you need to identify the type of noise you have and then apply the right filter.

Comment: The noise are groups of pixels, the one in the images i added, are 3 by 4 pixels